# Replacing set_value to at[ ]

Tags: python, pandas, knn

I am trying to rewrite this piece of code:

```
first_day_result = Spring2019.iloc[0]['Adj Close']
Spring2019.set_value( 0, 'KNN_Result', first_day_result)
```

The reason being set_value is not supported anymore. Instead it is recommend to use the following approach: set_value is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. **Please use `.at[]` or `.iat[]` accessors instead**

How do I do this, so it works with the following code:

```
for i in range(1, len(Spring2019)):
Spring2019.loc[i, 'KNN_Result'] = Spring2019.loc[i-1, 'KNN_Result'] + Spring2019.loc[i, 'Gain_or_Loss_KNN']
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `Spring2019.at[i, 'KNN_Result']` instead of `Spring2019.loc[i, 'KNN_Result']`

Comment: I’m glad to hear 